# How to give class name to a newly created element?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a new element like this:

```
var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
var t3=document.createElement("input");
t3.id = "txtEstStartDt"+index;
cell3.appendChild(t3);
```

As I have given an id to the element, I want to give a class.

```
t3.class = "abc";
```

Will this work?

Comment: className is the correct JavaScript term

Comment: You don't use jQuery at all - how comes there is jQuery tag and "jQuery" in question header?

Comment: @Regent Sorry.. That was by mistake..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an element's CSS class with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className)

```
t3.className = "abc";
```

Alternative in jQuery (since you tagged it such) would be

```
var t3 = $("<input/>",{"id":"txtEstStartDt"+index,"class":"abc"});
```

or later:

```
t3.addClass("abc");
```

but then it would be better to make it all jQuery.

Comment: Well, with jQuery alternative version it also should be, for example, `cell3.appendChild(t3[0]);`

Comment: the whole script would look different in jQuery :) with `$t3.appendTo($cell3) ` or such

Comment: Yes, or `$(cell3).append(t3);` or many other ways, I just want to mention that jQuery alternative requires others changes in code.